# How to Track lazy loading product pages in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, event-tracking

I am in the process of setting up enhanced Ecommerce for GA and have had a few requests of additional of what else the client would like to see in their reports. Once of which is;

**"We no longer have paginated pages,instead, the pages automatically
load more products when a user gets to the bottom of the page. How can I track how many times the does this?"**

Is there a way (using event tracking maybe?), that we can track every time a the page reloads new products as the URL is no longer changing. In order to compare with data from before this functionality change, it would be useful to see what the equivalent number of pages a user is seeing, ie, how many times the page adds new products to the page. Any code examples would be really helpful too.

Thanks,
Roxi

Comment: Too broad since this depends on your implementation. The principle is that every time the Javascript function that appends new results is finished (probably the success event of an ajax call) you do another send pageview call with a custom url and pagename (see "virtual pageview" in the docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#virtual-pageviews).

Comment: Thanks Eike, I've got some experience with virtual page views in the past so will see if we are able to track things this way. Thanks